# Recursive include Sequelize?

Tags: javascript, mysql, orm, sequelize.js

I have category that can have child categories

And when I'm doing findAll I want to include all of those nested, but I don't know the depth.

```
var includeCondition = { 
                         include: [
                            { 
                               model: models.categories,
                               as:'subcategory', nested: true 
                            }]
                       };

models.categories.findAll(includeCondition)
        .then(function (categories) {
            resolve(categories);
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            reject(err);
        })
});
```

The result brings me only one level nested include.

```
[  
   {  
      dataValues:{  

      },
      subcategory:{  
         model:{  
            dataValues:{  

            }
            // no subcategory here            
         }
      }
   }
]
```

Can I somehow make sequalize include those nested subcategories ?

Comment: Related: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/4890

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are few solutions if found for this
first one is more complicated but will give better performance:

This one is about implementing hierarchical data structure in MySQL
I like the guide here

http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

The one that is named The Nested Set Model.

The second solution that I actually implemented by myself is recursive expanding, this one uses lots of mysql requests and I believe can be improved, but it's a fast one and works well. The thing is to use for each category function like this

```
var expandSubcategories = function (category) {
    return new promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        category.getSubcategories().then(function (subcategories) {
            //if has subcategories expand recursively inner subcategories
            if (subcategories && subcategories.length > 0) {
                var expandPromises = [];
                _.each(subcategories, function (subcategory) {
                    expandPromises.push(expandSubcategories(subcategory));
                });

                promise.all(expandPromises).then(function (expandedCategories) {
                    category.subcategories = [];

                    _.each(expandedCategories, function (expandedCategory) {
                        category.subcategories.push(expandedCategory);
                    }, this);


                    //return self with expanded inner
                    resolve(category);
                });

            } else {
                //if has no subcategories return self
                resolve(category);
            }
        });
    });
};
```

So it's going through the categories and expanding them recursively.

Maybe this will help someone as well.

Answer (score 5):

This is ihoryam's answer adapted to ES6, using `async/await`, arrow functions `() =>` and Sequelize ORM to fetch the data, and not using Lodash.

```js
const getSubCategoriesRecursive = async (category) => {
  let subCategories = await models.category.findAll({
      where: {
          parentId: category.id
      },
      raw : true
  });

  if (subCategories.length > 0) {
      const promises = [];
      subCategories.forEach(category => {
          promises.push(getSubCategoriesRecursive(category));
      });
      category['subCategories'] = await Promise.all(promises);
  }
  else category['subCategories'] = []; 
  return category;
};
```

Async functions returning promises, you do not need to precise `return new promise(...)`

Comment: If you're just updating the code, make an edit to the answer. If you're attributing a new answer to yourself, add something new.

Answer (score 1):

There is a node module which handle it : [sequelize-hierarchy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-hierarchy)
It adds column *parentId* and *hierarchyLevel* to your table.
As an example, this is what I did to order employees skills in a tree.
Skills could be "*Macro*" -> "*Excel*" -> "*Office*" -> "*Computer*"

database.js:

```
const  Sequelize = require('sequelize');
require('sequelize-hierarchy')(Sequelize);
const sequelize = new Sequelize("stackoverflow", null, null, {
  dialect: "sqlite",
  storage: "database.db"
});
sequelize.sync().then(() => {console.log("Database ready");});
module.exports = sequelize;
```

skill.js:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Skill = sequelize.define("skill", {
    name:           DataTypes.STRING,
  });
  Skill.isHierarchy();
  return Skill;
};
```

Then in your controller:

```
Skill.findAll().then(skills => {
  res.send(skills); // Return a list
});
Skill.findAll({ hierarchy: true }).then(skills => {
  res.send(skills); // Return a tree
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sequelize currently has no support for common table expressions and recursive CTEs. Adding the ability to include a CTE into the find* family of methods would allow find* to perform recursive queries.

Here is the link for examples.

[Common Table Expressions and Recursive Queries](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/4890)

Answer (score 0):

sequelize-hierarchy is not compatible with Sequelize v6. And this is what i get from ChatGPT after trying Etienne Duverney code:

```
const getChildrenRecursive = async (menu) => {
  const childrenMenus = await models.Menu.findAll(
    { where: { parentId: menu.id }, raw: true },
  );
  const children = await Promise.all(childrenMenus.map(async (child) => {
    const childObj = {
      ...child,
      children: await getChildrenRecursive(child),
    };
    return childObj;
  }));
  return children;
};
```

This will give you all descendent from the given id. If there is no child the value will be empty array [].

Comment: Sharing code / answer generated with chat GPT is not allow : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned

Answer (score 0):

I used While to get children recursively:

```
async getChildrenRecursively(user, document) {
    const children = []; //here will be our final result
    const unprocessed = []; //the list children, that we need to search through
    unprocessed.push(document); //adding root element to the list
    while(unprocessed.length > 0) {
        const found = await this.getDocumentsByParentId(user, unprocessed[0].parentId); //function to get first level nested
        children.push(...found); //adding results to final result
        unprocessed.push(...found); //adding results to continue search
        unprocessed.shift(); //removing the element we just searched
    }
    return children;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Suppose you have 5 different models A, B, C, D, E and A is associated with B, B with C and so on.
So while fetching data for A you can get the all the nested subcategory hierarchy by using

`include: [{ all: true, nested: true }]`

Example:
   `A.findAll(where:{// add conditions}, { include: [{ all: true, nested: true }]});`

Comment: He is not asking for a solution for different models but for nesting the same model.