# Recursive postgresql query

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have 2 tables, `Categories` and `Products`.

A category can have multiple categories and products, and a product belongs to one category. I want to do a recursive query that find for each category find her products and categories and so on to the end of the tree.

- Product: (name, categoryId, id);
- Category: (name, categoryId, id); --- CategoryId is the Category Father Id

I try with this query

```
WITH RECURSIVE t AS (
SELECT "Categories"."CategoryId" as CategoryId, "Categories".name as CategoryName, "Products".name as ProductName, "Products"."CategoryId" as   CategoryIdProduct FROM "Categories"
JOIN "Products"
ON "Categories"."CategoryFatherId" = '34b176f6-dcac-4547-96a0-9224c94fb8e8' and "Products"."CategoryId" IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT a."CategoryId", a."name", s."productname", s."categoryidproduct"
FROM "Categories" a 
INNER JOIN t s ON a."id" = s.categoryid
)SELECT * FROM t;
```

But give this results that of course are not my goal:

```
[
 {
   "categoryid" : "34b176f6-dcac-4547-96a0-9224c94fb8e8",
    "productname" : "asdsad",
    "categoryname" : "sadad",
     "categoryidproduct" : "34b176f6-dcac-4547-96a0-9224c94fb8e8"
 },
 {
    "categoryid" : "34b176f6-dcac-4547-96a0-9224c94fb8e8",
     "productname" : "asdasd",
     "categoryname" : "sadasd",
     "categoryidproduct" : "2584c2ff-4e39-4b8a-b482-0802a1712114"
 },
 {
   "categoryid" : "34b176f6-dcac-4547-96a0-9224c94fb8e8",
   "productname" : "sad",
    "categoryname" : "sdaf",
    "categoryidproduct" : "34b176f6-dcac-4547-96a0-9224c94fb8e8"
 },
]
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  A db fiddle of some sort would also be helpful.

Comment: CONNECT BY searches might give you a clue

Comment: Connect by is not found in postgresql

Comment: The query you have shown is already a recursive query - but it will not return the JSON result you have shown. You are not using any JSON functions that would turn the "tabular result" of the query into your sample JSON. So something doesn't add up here

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34135555/recursive-include-sequelize